# Replace single quote(') with nothing in Hive

Tags: regex, hive, special-characters, hiveql, regexp-replace

I have a function to replace different types of characters with nothing like below.

```
CAST(TRANSLATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(number),' |,|-|/|&|_|''''',''),'.|(|)','') as string) as number
```

Everything is working fine, except the ''''' part, where i want to replace single quote/apostrophe with nothing.

Example:

```
TYLER'SCOFFEE should come out as TYLERSCOFFEE
```

I checked examples from this forum and it seems we can use a backslash to acheive the above, but when i use backslash like below, it throws an error.

```
select CAST(TRANSLATE(REGEXP_REPLACE('TYLER\'SCOFFEE',' |,|-|/|&|_|'\'',''),'.|(|)','') as string) as number;
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:68 character '\' not supported here (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Can someone help me on how to solve my problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use doble-quoted regexp. Inside double-quotes, single-quote is shielded:

```
select 'TYLER\'SCOFFEE' as original_str, regexp_replace('TYLER\'SCOFFEE',"'",'') result;
```

Result:

```
original_str    result
TYLER'SCOFFEE   TYLERSCOFFEE
```

Also if you need to replace many different characters with the same replacement, put all of them into `[]`, no need to use pipe `|`:

```
select regexp_replace('TYLER\'SCOFFEE ,-/&_', 
                      "[ ,-/&_']", 
                      '')
```

Result:

```
TYLERSCOFFEE
```

Comment: .Thank you, yes will use []