# How to escape single quotes in RLIKE Hive? Double single quotes not working

Tags: sql, hive, special-characters, hiveql, rlike

I would like to escape the single quote in RLIKE input. I used double single quotes like so:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE column RLIKE 'o''brien'
```

But it returned the results with `"obrien"` rather than `"o'brien"`. I tried `"\\'"` instead of double single quotes too, but that doesn't work either. So what is the correct escape character for single quote?

Answer (score 3):

Three methods:

1 Put the whole regexp into double-quotes, single quote is shielded inside double-quotes:

```
where column rlike "o'brien"
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66175603/2700344

2 Use unicode \u0027

```
where column rlike 'o\\u0027brien'
```

3 Use HEX \x27

```
where column rlike 'o\\x27brien'
```

Using `\\x` or `\\u` codes you can check any special character if you know it's code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `=`:

```
WHERE column = 'o''brien'
```

I'm not sure why you are using `RLIKE` unless you intent:

```
WHERE column LIKE '%o''brien%'
```

Comment: I simplified my command, I want to look for multiple patters so Regex is the best option (i.e. "(o''brien)||(mcdonald)" ). BTW, LIKE exhibits the same behavior too.